# How to check if the values are multiple in array or not in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have multiple values in the array as shown below:

```
[
    {
        "companyName": "ABC",
        "companyID": "0123"
    },
    {
        "companyName": "DEF",
        "companyID": "4567"
    },
    {
        "companyName": "GHI",
        "companyID": "8910"
    },
    {
        "companyName": "JHK",
        "companyID": "2345"
    },
    {
        "companyName": "LMN",
        "companyID": "6789"
    }
]
```

Now if the values in the array are multiple then it will print the "True" or else if the value in the array is single then it will print "False". Can anyone help me with this how to do this javascript?

Comment: if the name of array is `array`, the answer is `Boolean(array.length-1)`

Comment: @TheBombSquad the name of the array is `array` but can you explain to me in detail how to code this properly?

Comment: @DevalSoni what do you mean by this `values in the array are multiple`,
are you referring to multiple objects or objects with same `values`. Please elaborate.

Comment: @DevalSoni the logic is simple: `Boolean` takes in an argument and *converts* it to a boolean(true/false), and `array.length-1` would be 0 when singular or a positive number when more than 1, but one question: what to do if the array has NO values? `Boolea(array.length-1)` would print true whereas `array.length>1` would print false

Comment: @TheBombSquad got the logic. Thank you so much for your help.